# BQ Telegram Profile Picture

Tags: ubuntu-touch, telegram

I tried to add a picture on my profile on Telegram Application in my BQ Ubuntu unfortunately I cannot able to do so. Can you help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually found a bug. It's already fixed though in the upcoming release, so please check for updates around mid next week. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: This is indeed solved since today's update (1.3.4(101)).